# Passing multiple values from dialog in Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have created a dialog using Material Design for Angular. In the original example there was only one field, which was bound with one parameter in parent view. I want to create a dialog, that gathers more than just one parameter and return these parameters back to the parent component, so I can post it to my API.

How it looks now:

```
<h1 mat-dialog-title>Create</h1>
<div mat-dialog-content>
  <p>Fill in a new company name</p>
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput [(ngModel)]="data.name">
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
<div mat-dialog-actions>
  <button mat-button (click)="onNoClick()">Cancel</button>
  <button mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="data.name" cdkFocusInitial>Ok</button>
</div>
```

What I want to achieve:

```
<h1 mat-dialog-title>Create</h1>
    <div mat-dialog-content>
      <p>Fill in a new person name</p>
      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput [(ngModel)]="data.name">
        <input matInput [(ngModel)]="data.surname">
        <input matInput [(ngModel)]="data.email">
        <input matInput [(ngModel)]="data.mobile">
        ...
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <div mat-dialog-actions>
      <button mat-button (click)="onNoClick()">Cancel</button>
      <button mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="WHAT DO I ENTER HERE?" cdkFocusInitial>Ok</button>
    </div>
```

When I removed the `[mat-dialog-close]` property, the data never came back to the component and couldn't be sent to API. Could you advise on how do I pass back these multiple values?

Comment: `[mat-dialog-close]="data"`

Answer (score 3):

The only thing you have to do is to send the data from the child (modal in this case) to the parent is to pass `[mat-dialog-close]="data"` in the button, The parent can take care of the values sent via the `data` object, if the values are correctly assigned.

```html
  <button mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="data" cdkFocusInitial>Ok</button>
```

and

```js
data: {name: this.name, role: this.role}
```

See [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-igxsit-9zfzr7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdialog-overview-example-dialog.html) for an example. Both values you added are being printed in the console and passed into the parent's component `passedValues` object, which is printed in the HTML file.

```js
dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
  console.log('The dialog was closed');
  console.log('All the data', result);
  this.passedValues = result;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you have such case, in referring component you can easily use as you wanted

```js
    openDialog() {
        this.dialog.open(AddChargesComponent, {
          data: { name: this.name, surname:this.surname, email: this.email, mobile: this.mobile} 
        }).afterClosed().subscribe(response => {
          console.log(response.name,response.surname, response.email, response.mobile )
        })
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Roy's answer, you can pass a subset of the data like this:

```
  <button mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="{name: data.name, email: data.email}" cdkFocusInitial>Ok</button>
```